# Readability of the generated code in dart

Tags: javascript, dart

Darts generates complex javascript code at the moment. I see this as a major drawback and I actually prefer the TypeScript approach to the problem.

I would like to hear if anyone knows the strategic plan for Dart at that point. Will Dart generate - somewhat - understandable javascript in the future?

Comment: Dart is still in technical preview. At the moment the language specification has the version 0.0.6, a 0.0.7 is expected soon. It is far from "complete". Browser support: You can transcompile Dart to JavaScript, preferably with Frog (not DartC, it compiles to huge javascript files). Dartium is one of the browsers which supports native Dart, a controvers discussed Webkit branch is somewhere too. My personal expectation is to get something more concrete in the middle of next year. From my experience Google Devs are doing lots to make the language proper and good, borrowing not only from Java, but

Answer (score 7):

The question is: why would you be interested in looking at the compiled code?

dart2js produces [source maps](https://wiki.mozilla.org/DevTools/Features/SourceMap) for the compiled code.

You should see the "map files" when you compile to JavaScript. These source maps allow you to view and debug your code in the web browser (currently works in Chrome, support for Firefox in the works) as Dart code, even though it is executing JavaScript.

Even if you did not have source maps, you shouldn't have any need to debug JavaScript code. If your code does not run, it's either a problem in dart2js or your code and if it's your code, you can debug in Dartium or Chrome with source maps.

Answer (score 2):

I actually like the answer that starts with "The question is: why would you be interested in looking at the compiled code?", however, I would like to add:

- I don't think the generated JavaScript is that bad. Once you understand that foo$2 means foo is a function that takes 2 arguments, it's not that bad at all.
- The dart2js team is not trying to compile to JavaScript in a simple way. Actually, one of their goals is that the JavaScript they generate should be better and ideally faster than what you can write by hand. This is similar to the fact that C compilers can generate code that is faster than assembly you would write by hand because C compilers can do optimizations that are too hard for a limited human brain to accomplish. You can already see this happening when dart2js inlines certain functions.

However, as the first answer pointed out, the real answer is that we have source maps so that you should rarely need to look at the JavaScript.